# Displaying information from multiple threads in a single JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I start several(threads)  instances of a java class that receives an "input" and based on that generates an "output" on out it out on the standard output(screen). I would like to add an option that would enable me to send this output to a single JFrame (text area). What is the best way of doing this? Up to this point my program was totally GUIless but I would like to make it a bit more GUI friendly and add this option.

The challenge is that at any given point I could have several threads running. Any design or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and if you can use [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 2):

As MadProgrammer points out, a nice, encapsulated way of doing this is `SwingWorker`.

That said, here is the general theory:

All updates to Swing components must be done on the Swing event dispatch thread (there are some exceptions, but not relevant here).  This is achieved by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (and occasionally `invokeAndWait()` ).

The Swing runtime will then queue up the changes you want to make and call them one at a time.  This makes the entire problem of updating your text area pretty trivial:  just create a Runnable with the text you want to append, pass that to `invokeLater()`, and have your Runnable grab the document model of the text area and append your desired text to it.

`SwingWorker` can encapsulate some of the complexities of background thread management, but I encourage you to do it the 'hard way' a time or two (and your use-case is actually easier to do the 'hard way').  That way you can appreciate what `SwingWorker` does for you when you do need it.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to convert your existing threads to `SwingWorker`s. Just let them from time to time send messages to JFrame in a way like this:

```
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
       // update GUI
  });
```

To avoid boilerplate code, it is good to wrap programming interface to the screen with a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. An example of such wrapping is at [SwingProxyActorTest.java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/blob/master/df4j-core/test/org/df4j/core/ext/SwingProxyActorTest.java).